# How to return a default false if a property dont exists in values.yaml file?

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

yaml file .
i have a value as below defined under global

```
global:
  logging:
    log4j:
     enabled: true
```

I am also have a helper function

```
{{- define "helm-basic-template.logging-enabled" -}}
{{ .Values.global.logging.log4j.enabled | default "false" }}
{{- end -}}
```

it is possible the property global.logging.log4j.enabled may not exist , in that case i expect the helper function to return false, otherwise return the value of the property .
however it is not working as i expected . any idea what is wrong with my function ? or any other better way to re write it ?
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid variables being undefined, additional checks are needed here.

According to the [helm document](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/), when the object is empty, the if statement judges to return false.

A pipeline is evaluated as false if the value is:

- a boolean false
- a numeric zero
- an empty string
- a nil (empty or null)
- an empty collection (map, slice, tuple, dict, array)

Use the following checks directly.

```yaml
{{- if .Values.global }}
{{- if .Values.global.logging }}
{{- if .Values.global.logging.log4j }}
{{- if .Values.global.logging.log4j.enabled }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logging-cm
data:
  conf.json: |
    xxxxx
...
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Or employ a  named template approach.

```yaml
{{- define "helm-basic-template.logging-enabled" -}}
{{- $val := false }}
{{- if .Values.global -}}
{{- if .Values.global.logging -}}
{{- if .Values.global.logging.log4j -}}
{{- if .Values.global.logging.log4j.enabled -}}
{{- $val = true }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{ $val }}
{{- end -}}
```

Or use [default](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#default) to set a simple default value.

```yaml
{{- define "helm-basic-template.logging-enabled" -}}
{{- .Values.global.logging.log4j.enabled | default false .Values.global.logging.log4j.enabled -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Or use [dig](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#dig) to select keys from a list of values.

```yaml
{{- define "helm-basic-template.logging-enabled" -}}
{{- dig "logging" "log4j" "enabled" false .Values.global -}}
{{- end -}}
```